# Marshalling json.RawMessage returns base64 encoded string

Tags: json, go

I run the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    raw := json.RawMessage(`{"foo":"bar"}`)
    j, err := json.Marshal(raw)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(j))  
}
```

**Playground:** http://play.golang.org/p/qbkEIZRTPQ

**Output:**

```
"eyJmb28iOiJiYXIifQ=="
```

**Desired output:**

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

Why does it base64 encode my `RawMessage` as if it was an ordinary `[]byte`?

After all, RawMessage's implementation of MarshalJSON is just returning the byte slice

```
// MarshalJSON returns *m as the JSON encoding of m.
func (m *RawMessage) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return *m, nil 
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Found the answer in a [go-nuts thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Golang-Nuts/38ShOlhxAYY)

The value passed to `json.Marshal` must be a pointer for `json.RawMessage` to work properly:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    raw := json.RawMessage(`{"foo":"bar"}`)
    j, err := json.Marshal(&raw)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(j))  
}
```

Comment: How can I use its key and value from j variable?

Comment: @RockBalbao `j` is the JSON encoded string. To access the values, you need to use [json.Unmarshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal).