# Aggregating JSON objects in Go

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I'm making a Go service that gathers JSON objects from different sources and aggregates them in a single JSON object.

I was wondering if there was any way to aggregate the child objects without having to unmarshal and re-marshal them again or having to manually build a JSON string.

I was thinking of using a `struct` containing the already marshalled parts, such as this:

```
type Event struct {
    Place     string `json:"place"`
    Attendees string `json:"attendees"`
}
```

Where `Place` and `Attendees` are JSON strings themselves. I'd like to somehow mark them as "already marshalled" so they don't end up as escaped JSON strings but get used as is instead.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a custom type that implements [`Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) interface.

https://play.golang.org/p/YB_eKlfOND

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Event struct {
    Place     RawString  `json:"place"`
    Attendees RawString  `json:"attendees,omitempty"`
}

type RawString string

func (s RawString) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(s), nil
}

func main() {
    event := Event{
        Place: RawString(`{"name":"Paris"}`),
        Attendees: RawString(`[{"name":"John"}, {"name":"Juli"}]`),
    }
    s, err := json.Marshal(event)
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("event: %v; err: %v", string(s), err))
}
```

Comment: @KarrotKake, the RawMessage was the first thing that I tried, but it encodes to base64. Do you have a working example? I would be happy to check where I did wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`json.RawMessage`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage)

> RawMessage is a raw encoded JSON object. It implements Marshaler and Unmarshaler and can be used to delay JSON decoding or precompute a JSON encoding.

Also, `json.RawMessage` is an alias to `[]byte` so you can values to it this way:

```
v := json.RawMessage(`{"foo":"bar"}`)
```

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Event struct {
    Place     json.RawMessage `json:"place"`
    Attendees json.RawMessage `json:"attendees"`
}

func main() {
    e := Event{
         Place: json.RawMessage(`{"address":"somewhere"}`),
         Attendees: json.RawMessage(`{"key":"value"}`),
    }
    c, err := json.Marshal(&e)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(c))
    // {"place":{"address":"somewhere"},"attendees":{"key":"value"}}
}
```

Comment: I've tried to use RawMessage but it encodes the string to base64. Can you provide a working example? Just curious, as it was first what I tried.

Comment: I actually tried `RawMessage` as the contents I have really are `[]byte` and not `string` and it gets encoded in base64 too. If there's a workaround for this...

Comment: @Jukurrpa, you can inherit your custom class as `type RawBytes []byte`. Also curios about `RawMessage`.

Comment: You must have passed the json.RawMessage by value and not a pointer. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24229303/1826232